# Remove/Update Python3-dev

Tags: python, kali-linux, apt

I am trying to install a wireless driver on Kali; however, when I try to update certain files I get the following error:

```
└─$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3.9-dev                                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.9.7-1) but 3.9.8-1 is to be installed
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.9.8-1) but 3.9.7-1 is to be installed
               Depends: python3.9-dev (>= 3.9.8-0~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried using `apt-get --fix-broken install` and I get the same error. I can't update Python3 or remove it to reinstall it. Any direction here would be helpful.

Comment: This is a Kali question, not a security question.

Comment: Why are you purging Python3.9-dev if you're trying to install a wireless driver? Those tasks seem completely unrelated.